# How to delete node in XML file that has text content == var1 and a parent node with an attribute == var2 using XPathExpression in Java?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have an xml file that is formatted as follows:

```
<library>
    <playlists>
        <playlist id="0">
            <songs>
                <songId>2</songId>
                <songId>5</songId>
            </songs>
        </playlist>
        <playlist id="1">
            <songs>
                <songId>1</songId>
                <songId>5</songId>
                <songId>8</songId>
            </songs>
        </playlist>
    </playlists>
</library>
```

I am trying to delete the songId node whose text content matches the ID that I pass into a function and that's inside the playlist with an attribute ID that matches another value that I also have as an input to my function.

This is what my function looks like (I have omitted all the DocumentBuilderFactory, etc to keep this concise)

```
deleteSongFromPlaylist(int selectedPlayListId, int selectedSongId) {
        ...
        // Finds the node with the song id for the selected song in the selected play list for removal.
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/library/playlists/playlist[@id=\"" + selectedPlayListId + "\"]/songs[songId/text() = \"" + selectedSongId + "\"]");
        Node deleteSongNode = ((NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET)).item(0);

        // Removes the node corresponding to the title of the song.
        deleteSongNode.getParentNode().removeChild(deleteSongNode);
        ...
}
```

which results in a NullPointerException because the XPathExpression has an error in it.

I also suspect that the line:

```
deleteSongNode.getParentNode().removeChild(deleteSongNode);
```

will delete

```
<songs>
    <songId>1</songId>
    <songId>4</songId>
</songs>
```

and not only the songId node that I want to delete but I haven't been able to test this because I haven't gotten the XPathExpression to work.

So my questions are:

1. How do I fix my XPathExpression to point to the songId node that I want, where the playlist attribute and songId text content are both variables?
2. How do I delete only the songId node that the XPathExpression points to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select `songId` element, it has to be the last element in the main step expression. I'm using `.` to reference current context element here, but for this particular case, `text()` which return direct child text node should work as well. Another side note, single-quotes inside XPath string looks a bit tidier than escaped double-quotes, IMO :

```
String query = "/library/playlists/playlist[@id='" + selectedPlayListId + "']/songs/songId[. = '" + selectedSongId + "']";
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(query);
```

Also, if `songId` is unique, you can evaluate the XPath to a `NODE` instead of `NODESET` to return only one node at a time :

```
Node songId = (Node) expression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);
songId.getParentNode().removeChild(songId)
```